# UIButton is Filling Screen

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a problem where the button's I have added to .xib file are filling the screen when I run the application in the iPhone simulator.  In Interfacce Builder, the UI appears exactly as I want it.  It is added in Interface Builder, and it is correctly linked to the proper view controller.  The button is not being manipulated in the code.  Code someone point out some settings to check.  This is an error that has been there for a few and days, and I can't seem to fix it.

The view hierarchy is (if this helps):

```
MainWindow
    TabController
        FirstView
        SecondView
        ThirdView
```

In `FirstView.xib`, in the document outline under objects, there is a root view, which contains the `UIButton` in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that the button is added as the view, instead of a subview of the view. It sometimes happens, when you move a button around -- particularly from within the hierarchy list, it accidentally becomes the view (of the viewController) instead of be a subview.

Comment: I double checked, the button is a subview of the main view.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably is that you have not configured correctly the resizing of the button. You can either set it in code or using the interface builder.

For the interface builder solution select the button and open the "Size Inspector". You will see that there is an autosizing feature, adjust to your need and you are done.

Comment: Double checked the resizing.  Everything looks like it should display as wanted.

Comment: if the button is not being manipulated in the code then it has to do with the interface builder. Can you post the again the hierarchy adding all controls involved ?

Comment: Since I didn't get too far into the project, I scrapped it and started over.  IF I run into the same problem, I'll add an update.